# chrome extension call to gmail api

Tags: google-chrome-extension, gmail-api

I am really new creating chrome extensions. I am trying to use Gmail API in my extension to get the Thread Id from sent email folder. I have used this tutorial:
https://medium.com/streak-developer-blog/how-to-use-the-gmail-api-in-a-chrome-extension-a272b2405b57
When I use the function getThreads(query, labels),
https://gist.github.com/omarstreak/7908035c91927abfef59

I did not get nothing. Also when I review the background console appear this error:
Unchecked runtime.lastError while running identity.getAuthToken: OAuth2 request failed: Service responded with error: 'bad client id: {0}'

I have created my own client_id and I put it in my manifest.

```
 "oauth2": {
"client_id": "27599747390-.................apps.googleusercontent.com",
"scopes": [
  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify"
]
```

},

Have someone some tutorial or sample that works about using Gmail API in chrome extensions?.

Comment: Yes, there is actually a sample in the documentation. See [this method](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/threads/get) if your purpose is to get a specified thread. Also to guide you accordingly, here is a [github post](https://github.com/GoogleDeveloperExperts/chrome-extension-google-apis) to help you more on chrome extension essentials.

Comment: Thank you so much MαπμQμαπkγVπ.0, I am going to review these information :D.

Comment: does this answer your question? good luck in your project.

Comment: Yes,  this information helped me a lot. Thank you so much.

Comment: could you share the completed code? or explain how the solutions helped you?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is actually a sample in the documentation. See [this method](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/threads/get) if your purpose is to get a specified thread. Also to guide you accordingly, here is a [github post](https://github.com/GoogleDeveloperExperts/chrome-extension-google-apis) to help you more on chrome extension essentials.